# Color by NetworkX node attribute in Bokeh and Holoviews network visualization

Tags: python, networkx, bokeh, holoviews

I'm trying to use `bokeh` and `holoviews` to create an interactive network visualization.  However, I cannot figure out how to pass node attributes into the Holoviews graph to then color by the attribute values. My `networkx` graph has a bunch of different node attributes, and ultimately I would love to have a drop down menu that allows me to pick the attribute to color by, as well as for the attributes to appear in the hover tooltip.  However, for now, I just want to be able to color by any of the node attributes.

I've been following all of the [bokeh examples](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html) and all of the [holoviews examples](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Network_Graphs.html) that I can find, but I can't seem to figure it out. The Facebook example looks promising, but I can't believe that I would have to take my data out of `networkx` and into `pandas` to be able to do this.

**How can I adjust my code below to color the nodes by their NetworkX node attributes?**

```
import networkx as nx
import holoviews as hv

hv.extension('bokeh')

%opts Graph [width=400 height=400]

# create an example graph
g = nx.karate_club_graph()

# look at node attributes
g.nodes[0]
{'club': 'Mr. Hi'}

# load network into holoviews
graph = hv.Graph.from_networkx(g, nx.spring_layout)

# define color palette
colors = ['#000000']+hv.Cycle('Category20').values

# set plotting options
plot_opts = dict(color_index='club', 
                 xaxis=None, 
                 yaxis=None, 
                 show_frame=False)

# set stple options
style_opts = dict(node_size=15, 
                  cmap=colors,
                  edge_line_width=2, 
                  edge_alpha=0.3)

# apply options to plot
padding = {'x': (-1.2, 1.2), 'y': (-1.2, 1.2)}
graph = graph.redim.range(**padding).opts(style=style_opts, plot=plot_opts)

# show plot
graph
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Currently the Graph.from_networkx method does not support extracting node attributes so you would indeed have to do this manually, which does seem like a major oversight. Would you mind filing an issue as a feature request?

Comment: Thanks for the response @philippjfr.  I'll open an issue requesting this feature.

Comment: Or how to color them at all? I don't find anything about it.